# xmlhttprequest is not opening. struggling student

Tags: javascript, html

currently a student and struggling to get XMLHttprequest to open my local pdf.

Please could someone assist.

Comprehensive Rules

```
<div>
    <script>
            function loadXMLDoc() 
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
                {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

                else 
                {
                    // code for older browsers
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
                {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("comprules").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    }
                };

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "MagicCompRules_20170825.pdf", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't read local files with JavaScript as that would be a huge security problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @str is right, you can't use a http request to open a local file unless you have a web server that will serve it up for you. Sounds like you have plenty of homework to do

Comment: why are you placing a script inside a div tag

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. It was the server that wasnt up. @Mikkel